# Losing input focus on AndroidTV

Tags: android, android-tv

I am having a pretty bizarre bug on AndroidTV.

I am opening an `AlertDialog` in the app and in 10-20% cases I am **totally losing remote input focus**. The buttons that are handled globally (e.g. HOME) work correctly, but DPAD, OK and other remote buttons do nothing.

In logcat, I see this:

```
W: Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT, scanCode=105, metaState=0, flags=0x28, repeatCount=0, eventTime=4748412, downTime=4748300, deviceId=9, source=0x301 }    
W: Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT, scanCode=105, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=4748468, downTime=4748468, deviceId=9, source=0x301 }    
W: Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT, scanCode=105, metaState=0, flags=0x28, repeatCount=0, eventTime=4748570, downTime=4748468, deviceId=9, source=0x301 }
```

I checked `adb shell dumpsys window` output for any focus anomalies but nothing comes across as weird.

My guess would be that the **focus is being blocked by something**, but I have no clue what that could be. I would be grateful for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't see your code but it might be race conditioning issue because you mentioned that it was "10-20% cases". You can have two way to figure out.
1. Try add logs in onKeyDown or onKeyUp method in your activity to see what will happen when you hit buttons on your remote.
2. Call "yourview.requestFocus()" in your dialog when you launch it. Note that yourview is the rootview for your dialog, just change to whatever for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your button and set key listener on your button like this

```
yourButton.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    // your code here
                    return true;

                } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
                    return true;
                }

                else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) {
                    return true;
                }

                else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT) {
                    return true;
                }

                else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP) {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Some keypoints to note:

1. For performing action on device use DPAD center button and while testing on emulator use KEYCODE Enter button.
2. your avd should have dpad enabled. You can set these in the avd configurations.